# XSL: Search for node name

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to search for the child node that starts with "php"

```
<globals-cookie>
    <utma>1.959760512.1318348214.1318348214.1318348214.1</utma>
    <utmz>1.1318348214.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)</utmz>
    <phpsessid34534>826427ef2fade7f9471581a429ce266d</phpsessid34534>
    <utmb>122420241.88.10.1321257433</utmb>
    <utmc>122420241</utmc>
</globals-cookie>
```

I would write `//globals-cookie/phpsessid34534`, but the number changes on the end..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this XPath:

```
globals-cookie/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'php')]
```

Comment: I found `//globals-cookie/*[starts-with(name(), 'php')]` which is very similar, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the XPath to such a node as you describe would be:

`/globals-cookie/*[starts-with(local-name(.),'php']`

Secondly, this is what attributes are for - Something like this would be more sensible.

```
<php sessid="34534">826427ef2fade7f9471581a429ce266d</php>
```

Comment: `Something like this would be more sensible.` - you assume I can change the XML

Comment: I assume no such thing - that's why I gave you both the answer to the question as asked, and a suggested improvement to the xml, rather than just one or the other.